# CMAKE not propagating correct value to code

Tags: cmake

I am declaring a CMAKE variable as follows:

```
set(NUM_THREADS "3" CACHE STRING "Number of OpenMP threads to use")
set_property(CACHE NUM_THREADS PROPERTY STRINGS "3")
```

Later, I pass this value to my app as follows:

```
if (OpenMP_CXX_FOUND)
    target_link_libraries(myapp PRIVATE OpenMP::OpenMP_CXX)
    target_compile_definitions(myapp PRIVATE NUM_OPENMP_THREADS=${NUM_THREADS})
endif()
```

Now, I call cmake as:

```
cmake -DNUM_THREADS=2 .
```

and I can compile the program. I also can see after running `cmake` and launching the `ccmake` GUI that this `NUM_THREADS` is set to 2.

I use it in my C++ code as:

```
std::cout << NUM_OPENMP_THREADS << std::endl;
```

And this always prints 3!

Comment: This is peculiar, I'm not able to reproduce this behavior. What steps do you use to compile after running `cmake -DNUM_THREADS=2 .`? I'm thinking somehow CMake is re-running again after this (using "3" instead), but before compilation? Can you add something like `VERBOSE=1` to the compilation to see that the preprocessor definition is what you expect.

Comment: @squareskittles This is interesting. Yes, I will dig further and update here. MY cmake version is 3.13.4. Which version are you using?

Comment: In terms of compilation, I just run `make` after that. So nothing else. I will try with the verbose

Comment: I'm using CMake 3.17, although that should not make a difference. What did `make VERBOSE=1` show? Can you add this output to your question post?